# Using Android 2.3 Front Camera SDK with an Android 2.1 app

Tags: android, camera, compatibility

I'm developing an Android application that uses the camera and will run on Android versions 2.1 an above.

I would like to give an option to switch camera for devices using Android 2.3.

How can I use Android 2.3 SDK without crashing on previous versions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd have to isolate the 2.3 front-facing camera code in one class and have another class for pre-2.3 one-camera support.

See [Contacts - Supporting the old and new APIs in the same application](http://Supporting%20the%20old%20and%20new%20APIs%20in%20the%20same%20application) for an example of how to handle supporting old and new APIs in one app.

[EDIT: Changed from referencing a desired minimum SDK level to 2.1, which is referenced in the title]
You'd also have to target the 2.3 SDK while specifying a minSDK of 2.1 API.

Comment: I would recommend only going back to Android 1.6.  Not many devices are on 1.5, and you gain a lot by using 1.6.

Comment: Edited answer from referencing a desired minimum SDK level to 2.1, which is referenced in the title

Answer (score 1):

1. Set your target SDK level at API level 9 (2.3), but your minimum SDK level at 2.1 or below
2. Use reflection to access the Android 2.3 APIs - this will fail on Android devices that don't have the APIs and you can provide an alternative.

See: [Backward Compatibility for Applications](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/backward-compatibility.html), [Android and Reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754714/android-and-reflection) and [java.lang.Reflect documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).