# Android Country Detector not found

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to use Country Detector which I can see in android sdk-23 location folder.

[image]

But even when I import whole location package, this class is not found.

[image]

I've even kept min sdk support as 23 only.

[image]

What am I missing on? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The class `CountryDetector` may be in the sources but it is not included in the official API - and the API is the library your project uses as main library. 
Therefore you can not access this class directly.

In this special case CountryDetector is a system service which you can request via `Context.getSystemService` (see [answer from *Shanmugapriya D*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38071279/150978)).

In other cases the following applies:

If you want to use this unofficial class you have to use it via Java reflection.

See for example here:
[Android and reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754714/android-and-reflection)

Alternatively you can try to build a JAR file and add it in Gradle as `provided`.

Answer (score 2):

**You do not instantiate this class directly; instead, retrieve it through
 * {@link android.content.Context#getSystemService
 * Context.getSystemService(Context.COUNTRY_DETECTOR)}.**
For more refer you can open that java file and check