# Replace method implementation in Android via reflection / class loader

Tags: android, reflection, code-injection, method-swizzling, runtimemodification

I am currently doing research on techniques for runtime manipulation on mobile applications. On the iOS platform I can easily do method swizzling by calling objective-c runtime library functions such as class_replaceMethod(...). Is an equivalent way possible on Android?

If I use the JDB, I can alter local variables and I can evaluate expressions. By means of the latter, I assume it is possible to change entire implementation bodies of methods. How would you exactly do this, e.g. with using reflections? What are the required steps?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9260228/6950238) answer.

Comment: Thank you for the link. So it is basically not possible with reflection to change the entire implementation of a method. Are there any other ways how i could achieve this?

Comment: "to change entire implementation bodies of methods" - why not use OOP and just override methods?

Comment: I am an security intern and currently exploring techniques how to manipulate runtime behavior of other applications. That's why I want to replace the implementation without changing the actual code of the APK file. A goal is among others, to local bypass login mechanisms by this way.

Comment: In this case may be [this](http://shadowwhowalks.blogspot.ru/2013/01/android-hacking-hooking-system.html) will be interesting for You.